# x:Bind Converter and FallbackValue not collaborating (UWP 10)

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I have a problem that involves a bunch of code, but I've isolated it down. If you want a TL;DR; jump to it further down. If you want a bit of context, here's my situation:

I have created three data converters for my bindings. One of them is a "string prefixer": it prefixes whatever you put in with a fixed string. In the current example, that fixed string is `"ms-appx:///cache/"`. The second one turns a `string` type into an `ImageSource`, and the third one chains multiple converters together.

I've then created a Xaml resource which is called `LocalCacheFile`. Everything works as you would think. Xaml code for this looks like so:

```
<Image Source="{x:Bind imageSource,Converter={StaticResource LocalCacheFile}}" />
```

However, I'm having the following problem. If I try to use the FallbackValue to put a placeholder image for when `imageSource` is empty, I get weird behaviour in `x:Bind` only.

The following code **works** as one would expect:

```
<Image Source="{Binding imageSource,FallbackValue='ms-appx:///Assets/default.png',Converter={StaticResource LocalCacheFile}}" />
```

But

```
<Image Source="{x:Bind imageSource,FallbackValue='ms-appx:///Assets/default.png',Converter={StaticResource LocalCacheFile}}" />
```

does not!

I've isolated it down to just one converter and it is `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` that x:Bind seems not to be handling.

**TL;DR;**
Here is the code for my string prefixer, which if I use alone as a test triggers the same faulty behaviour:

```
public class StringPrefix : IValueConverter
{
    public string prefix { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type typeName, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || value == null || (string)value == "")
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue ;

        return (prefix + value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type typeName, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The above converter works as you would expect it to (i.e. if the input string is empty, the fallback value is properly used) when using `Binding`. It raises a type exception when used with `x:Bind`.

What's up with this?

---

**Edit:** details about the exception.

This is the generated code:

```
        private void Update_project_imageSource(global::System.String obj, int phase)
        {
            if((phase & ((1 << 0) | NOT_PHASED | DATA_CHANGED)) != 0)
            {
                XamlBindingSetters.Set_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Image_Source(this.obj16, (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource)this.LookupConverter("LocalCacheFile").Convert(obj, typeof(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource), null, null), null);
            }
        }
```

Exception details:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.__ComObject' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource'.
  Source=Test
  StackTrace:
       at Test.Pages.ProjectView.ProjectView_obj1_Bindings.Update_project_imageSource(String obj, Int32 phase)
       at Test.Pages.ProjectView.ProjectView_obj1_Bindings.Update_project(Project obj, Int32 phase)
       at Test.Pages.ProjectView.ProjectView_obj1_Bindings.Update_(ProjectView obj, Int32 phase)
       at Test.Pages.ProjectView.ProjectView_obj1_Bindings.Update()
       at Test.Pages.ProjectView.<.ctor>b__6_0(FrameworkElement s, DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
  InnerException:
```

(to me, it looks like the generated code just doesn't deal with the default value possibility. Btw, that `__ComObject` is the `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.

**Edit 2**: I should add that if I change the Convert function to return null instead of DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, `x:Bind` functions, but then neither `x:Bind` nor `Binding` do their expected job of using the `FallbackValue`

Comment: Could you add the details about the `TypeException`?

Comment: I've added the exception info.

Comment: Not as solution, but as workaround: How about using the `paramater` to provide the fallback value, rather than the actual `FallbackValue` of the binding itself?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that too. There's 2 advantages to FallbackValue: runtime, and design time benefit.

In the end, I've just opted to kludge around the runtime solution (i.e. by having a placeholder image be copied) especially given that I don't foresee any scaling issues with my data model.

That said, I think this is a genuine bug.

Another annoyance with x:Bind (the reason why I had to chain converters): once you convert, type coercion is lost. You can bind to a Source attribute with the data being of string type, but you can't if a converter outputs a string. It's annoying.

Comment: I'd agree that this is a bug. But I'm kinda curious, why the hell there's a COM_Object... Make sure to report this bug to https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn ! If any response is created there, make sure to update this question as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `FallbackValue` in `Binding` and `x:Bind` is different.

In `Binding`, [`FallbackValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.fallbackvalue) is the value to use when the binding is unable to return a value.

> A binding uses **FallbackValue** for cases where the [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.path) doesn't evaluate on the data source at all, or if attempting to set it on the source with a two-way binding throws an exception that's caught by the data binding engine. **FallbackValue** is also used if the source value is the dependency property sentinel value [DependencyProperty.UnsetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue).

But in `x:Bind`, [`FallbackValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204783.aspx#properties_you_can_set) specifies a value to display when the source or path cannot be resolved. It can't work with `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.

As you've already know, `x:Bind` generates code at compile-time and it's  strongly typed. When you use `Converter` in `x:Bind`, it will regard the `Converter`'s return value of the same type as the target property and cast it like in your code:

```
(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource)this.LookupConverter("LocalCacheFile").Convert(obj, typeof(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource), null, null)
```

If you return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` in your `Converter`, it will throw exception as `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` can't cast to `ImageSource`.

For your scenario, you can use `TargetNullValue`.

> **TargetNullValue** is a similar property with similar scenarios. The difference is that a binding uses **TargetNullValue** if the Path and Source do evaluate, but the value found there is null.

For example using following code is XAML.

```
<Image Source="{x:Bind imageSource, TargetNullValue='ms-appx:///Assets/default.png', Converter={StaticResource LocalCacheFile}}" />
```

And in the `Convert`, return `null` instead of `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.

This works when running the app and the `imageSource` is empty. But to gain design time benefit, we still need use `FallbackValue`. So we can use `x:Bind` like following:

```
<Image Source="{x:Bind imageSource, TargetNullValue='ms-appx:///Assets/default.png', FallbackValue='ms-appx:///Assets/default.png', Converter={StaticResource LocalCacheFile}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is great! I don't know how it happened, but I didn't see it until a year after. I've marked it as solved, sorry about the delay!

Comment: This is a really good example of why in UWP we DO NOT return `UnsetValue` from converters!

Answer (score 3):

In `x:Bind` the `FallBackValue` is really only used for designtime data. Now, let's talk about something more important. Why use `x:Bind`. With the cost of spinning up an `IValueConverter`, are you convinced `x:Bind` is worth it? I'm not. When I see developers struggling to get `x:Bind` to work right for bindings OUTSIDE of a list, my recommendation is to switch to `binding`. Every time. Inside a list, compiled binding has a "repeat" value, but anywhere else, you have to prove to me that it is worth the effort - if it is otherwise difficult. Typically `x:bind` is great. But in cases like this, and cases like `UpdateSourceTrigger` falling back to or defaulting to `binding` is perfectly fine.